# Using IF condition to impute values from Two Columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table that looks something like this in Google Sheets:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **2** | Others | Maufacturing | Manufacturing |
| **3** | Manufacturing | MAnufacturing | Manufacturing |
| **4** | Others | Others | Others |
| **5** | Others |  | Others |

I want to add a formula in column C that will return:

- IF `A2="Others"` return the value in `B2`. Since `B2="Manufacturing"` hence `C2="Manufacturing"`
- IF `A3="Manufacturing"` return the value in `A3`. Hence `C3="Manufacturing"`
- If `A4="Others"` and `B4="Others"` return `B4`. Hence `C4="Others"`
- If `A5="Others" and` B5=""`return`A5`. Hence` C5="Others"`

There are 100s of unique values in column A.

I have tried the following formula:

```
=IFS(ISBLANK(A2), "",
     OR(A2="Manufacturing", A2="Manufacturer"),  "Manufacturing",
     OR(A2="Others", A2="Other"), "Others" )
```

Comment: is the value `"Others"` actually a placeholder for multiple different values in your table? e.g. `"Others" = OR("Other01", "Other02", "Other03", "Other04", etc.)`  and why do you mention `"Manufacturer"` in your formula?  Is that another placeholder for an array of possible values?   PS: I added in the missing double quotes and closing bracket to your formula so that it doesn't error out.

Answer (score 0):

There are various errors in your formula, including  value's names.
Try this:

```
=IFS( 
ISBLANK(A2),"", 
or( and (A2="Others", B2="Manufacturing"),and (A2="Manufacturing", B2="Manufacturing")),"Manufacturing", 
or( and (A2="Others", B2="Others"),A2 ="Others"), "Others" 
)
```

If you were to use it with the arrayformula() function you will have to eliminate the "and" and "or" like this:

```
=arrayformula(
IFS( 
ISBLANK(A2:A),"", 
(A2:A="Others")*(B2:B="Manufacturing"),"Manufacturing",
(A2:A="Manufacturing")*(B2:B="Manufacturing"),"Manufacturing", 
(A2:A="Others")*(B2:B="Others"),"Others", 
A2:A ="Others","Others" 
)
)
```

Comment: I will try this and update here but the function is going to get too long!

Comment: Explain better what column A contains and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your goal is to return the first value <> "Others".

Try this in C2:

```
=ArrayFormula(if((A2:A="Others")*(B2:B<>""),B2:B,A2:A))
```